# How to use "this" of jQuery.each() in a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please advise where i'm going wrong with the following?  I want the system to alert the anchor text for each list item in a loop but cant think how to structure the 'this' syntax?

```
$('.jsGrid ul li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $('this .overlayContent a').text());

});
```

Cheers
Paul

Comment: alert(index + ': ' + $('.overlayContent a',this).text());

Comment: Please post your html - I tried to guess it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Jf7ub/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert(index + ': ' + $('.overlayContent a',this).text());
```

Comment: Does my HTML not match the selectors? This does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Jf7ub/

Comment: But that is not what you posted as answer?!

Comment: well i answered based on the code you provided , if you post half of the code you'll get half of the answer... next time post the entire code right away and not in a comment.

Comment: What are you talking about? I am not the OP. Your answer is not the same code you use in the fiddle. So I ask why not and how would the code in the answer work if the one in the fiddle does not work if I use that example - at least not on my html - I appreciate any reason for the code not working

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a variable and won't get recognized inside of a string.  Construct the jQuery object around it and use `find` to get the anchor element you are looking for:

```
alert(index + ': ' + $(this).find('.overlayContent a').text());
```

If you search for `$("this .overlayContent a")` - jQuery will look for elements constructed like this:

```
<this>
   <div class='overlayContent'><a>Some text here</a></div>
</this>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.jsGrid ul li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).find('.overlayContent a').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use this keyword like this. instead use this

```
$('.jsGrid ul li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $('this').find('a').text());
});
```

or you cando like this'

```
$('.jsGrid ul li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $('this').children().text());
});
```